# Reading a specific part of the lines and storing it

Tags: python

I have a file(text) which contains data and below is one of the lines from the file

"xiakuram_4bitaddrk1.xifull_addrk2.xx1.xxdrv.xmna.mn1                 0.0000e+00      5.0000e-07      5.0000e-07  Vd = (1.456e-05, 1.479e-05) Vg = (1.08, 1.08) Vs = (0, 0) Vb = (0, 0)"

I only want to extract 5.0000e-07 from the line.(using python)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this number always before Vd? Also, I feel like it is a 3-D coordinate, do you want to extract the second or the third one?

Comment: 1) What did you try so far?
2) What is "special" about 5.0000e-07? If you do not tell us, we have on pattern to look for, and ultimately we cannot help you

Comment: Yes it is always before Vd and I want to extract the third one

Comment: That value is the time period and I want to store that in a variable, I'm able to print the line. But I'm stuck at the extraction of that value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number you want to extract is always right before `Vd`:

- split the string into a list with a space separator
- take the value just before `Vd` in the list

In python:

```
data = "xiakuram_4bitaddrk1.xifull_addrk2.xx1.xxdrv.xmna.mn1 0.0000e+00 5.0000e-07 5.0000e-07 Vd = (1.456e-05, 1.479e-05) Vg = (1.08, 1.08) Vs = (0, 0) Vb = (0, 0)" 
word_list = data.split(" ") 
time_period = word_list[word_list.index("Vd")-1]
print(time_period)
```

Output:

```
5.0000e-07
```